# rdlc report grouping data sort by numeric column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I'm using rdlc report in C#. Inside rdlc report I had added one parent group and report shows data as I expected, Only problem is that I want to sort data by `RowId` Column This `RowId` is an `int` type(DataSet Column). Sort Order shows option `A to Z` and  `Z to A`. Reference image is attached here.
Suppose I have Row Id 1, 2,3,4 ....40. This report will sort data like 1,11, 12,13...., 2, 21,.......
How to sort this data in order of 1,2,3,4.....40

[image: SortbyOrder]

I'm using visual studio 2015. 
Is there any other way to sort data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got solution to this problem, I use expression for converting existing value to int. Expression used is as below,

```
 =CInt(Fields!RowId.Value)
```